# PSFTP - Download to server on network

Tags: download, directory, sftp, shared

I'm using PSFTP to download files and using a local directory (i.e. `C:\Folder path\`) works. My problem is downloading to a Shared Folder.

I use `lcd C:\Folder path\` and it works.
Using `lcd \\NetworkServer\Folder` does not. Is there a different command I need to use or PSFTP only writes on local drive?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you cannot make UNC path a working directory.

But you can specify non-current directory as a download target with `get` command:

```
get file \\NetworkServer\Folder
```